# Переменные как ключ к массиву javascript ?

Tags: javascript

ДОбре! Сразу к делу! вот такой такой код не работает??

```
 var count = 5;

 var arr[count] = 'blabla';
```

в PHP такой фокус возможет вполне и легко а как быть в Javascrypt???

Comment: в яваскрипте нет ассоциативных массивов, в нем используются объекты

Comment: И как быть тогда(((?? Т_т

Comment: >И как быть тогда

я бы даже сказал, что возможность делать такие штуки в PHP - это скорее недостаток и хороший способ выстрелить себе в ногу

Comment: > И как быть тогда(((?? Т_т

Для начала - читать литературу по языку _до_ того, как начинать писать на нём. Очень помогает общему пониманию того, что вы вообще делаете.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Инициализировать сначала переменную явно...

```
var count = 5;
var arr = [];
arr[count] = "blahblah";
```

С объектами в качестве ассоциативных массивов так же:

```
var arr = {}
arr["key"] = "value";
```

Comment: спасибо) вы просто ВОООЛШЕПНИК)

Comment: @DanteLoL не забываем, что в числовом массиве (первый пример) таким способом мы создадим кроме 5ого элемента еще и все предыдущие за ним (4,3...).

Comment: @lampa, это кстати интересный вопрос, а создаются ли промежуточные элементы? По идее обращение к несуществующему элементу возвращает undefined как в массиве, так и в объекте. Вполне допустим такой код:

    arr = [];
    arr[5] = "value";
    for(i=0;i<10;i++) console.log(arr[i]);
    console.log(arr[100]);

То есть не важно какой индекс массива указывается, если по нему существует элемент, он вернется, а если не существует, то вернется undefined. Мне кажется они на самом деле не существуют, но внутренние функции работают с диапазоном от 0 до Array.lenght и поэтому захватывают их тоже.

Answer (score 3):

В отличие от PHP, в JavaScript необходимо объявлять переменные *до* их использования. Именно для этого служит ключевое слово `var`. Оно позволяет инициализировать переменные, но важно понимать, что присвоенеи значения элементу массива не является инициализацией массива. Поэтому правильный вариант:

```
var arr = [];
arr[count] = 'blabla';
```

**P. S.**

Что за дурацкий аргумент "*в PHP такой фокус возможет вполне и легко*"? PHP не JavaScript, логично, что их синтаксисы отличаются.